# add Excel RTD Server project type in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, add-in, rtd

I will like to create something similar to: http://www.add-in-express.com/docs/net-excel-rtd-servers.php

When I open visual studio I do not have that project type even though I am running it as an administrator...

[image]

what do I have to do so that I can have that project type (*ADX RTD Server*) on visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to have Add-in Express for Office and .net installed. There is no trial version for Visual Studio 2010, but if you have VS 2012, you can download a 60-day evaluation version of Add-in Express from Visual Studio Gallery:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/A4880BFE-A230-44B6-9D23-86AFAA1A2997